# Given that A is an nxn symmetric matrix, show that $(Av)\cdot w=v\cdot (Aw) $

Tags: linear-algebra

Here v and w are column vectors in $R^n$. What are the properties that I need to use to show this is true?

Edit: Just needed tranpose, so we have

$(Av)w=(Av)^Tw=v^tA^tw=v^TAw=v^T(Aw)=v\cdot(Aw) $

Comment: If $v$ and $w$ are $n \times 1$ column vectors and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then the products $Avw$ and $vAw$ do not make sense, as the dimensions are not compatible.

Comment: You are missing the transpose?